# .net datagridviewcheckboxcolumn

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have programmatically added a datagridviewcheckboxcolumn as such:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn cb = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cb);
```

It adds the column of check boxes fine, but it won't allow me to check any of them when I click on them?  Anybody know why?

Thanks.

Comment: are you working in edit templet??

Comment: It should work. Have you checked that you're not setting it to ReadOnly after it's added?

Comment: @Hansmukh - no i'm not using edit template   @Rox - It's definately not Read Only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set these properties of your `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn cb`

```
 cb.Frozen = false;
 cb.ReadOnly = false;
```