# Unable to check or uncheck DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn cells programmatically

Tags: c#, datagridview, checkbox

I'm trying to change DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn's items via this code

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvUser in UsersGrid.Rows)
        {
          dgvUser.Cells["ChkSelect"].Value = true;
        }
```

the value of checkboxs changed but the checkboxs on UI stay uncheck.

How to do it ?

Comment: Have you set these properties on the GridView? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4126497/1073107

Comment: Posted code works.  Problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the Datagridview and Refresh then.

DataGrid_ABC.Update(); in order to update the changes in the gridview

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the `DataGridViewCheckboxCell` acts differently from other cells. For some reason, the property which is used to determine how the checkbox should be drawn (checked or unchecked) is not `Value` but `FormattedValue`

My feeling though is that that the Value setter has been overriden in DataGridViewCheckBoxCell to act correctly. So if you call it on a `DataGridViewCell` you are using the **base** one (which does not affect FormattedValue) while if you cast the cell things should work:

```
((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)  dgvUser.Cells["ChkSelect"]).Value = true;
```

Comment: this also does not help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem when I tried clearing other checkbox columns in the same row (performed within the CellValueChanged method).  To fix my issue, I needed the following code:

```
private void dgv_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // filter for valid DataGridViewCheckBoxCell columns, if desired
    dgv.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}
```